# PyMC3 Multivariate Mixture Model: Constraining components to be non-empty

Tags: python, theano, mcmc, pymc3, mixture-model

I am implementing a Personalized Mixture of Multivariate Gaussian Regressions in `pymc3` and running into an issue with empty components. After referring to the [related PyMC3 mixture model example](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/master/pymc3/examples/gaussian_mixture_model.ipynb), I tried implementing the model using univariate normals instead, but I've had [some issues there as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35371811/2486302).

I've tried several strategies to constrain each component to be non-empty, but each has failed. These are shown in the code below. My specific question is: **What is the best way to constrain all components to be non-empty in a mixture of multivariate Gaussians using `pymc3`?**

Note that attempt #1 in the code below comes from the [Mixture Model in PyMC3 Example](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/master/pymc3/examples/gaussian_mixture_model.ipynb) and does not work here.

You can replicate the synthetic data I am using with the [function in this gist](https://gist.github.com/macks22/7853e65d8fd136b40613).

```
import pymc3 as pm
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
from scipy import stats

# Extract problem dimensions.
N = X.shape[0]  # number of samples
F = X.shape[1]  # number of features
pids = I[:, 0].astype(np.int)  # primary entity ids
uniq_pids = np.unique(pids)  # array of unique primary entity ids
n_pe = len(uniq_pids)  # number of primary entities

with pm.Model() as gmreg:
    # Init hyperparameters.
    a0 = 1
    b0 = 1
    mu0 = pm.constant(np.zeros(F))
    alpha = pm.constant(np.ones(K))
    coeff_precisions = pm.constant(1 / X.var(0))

    # Init parameters.
    # Dirichlet shape parameter, prior on indicators.
    pi = pm.Dirichlet(
        'pi', a=alpha, shape=K)

    # ATTEMPT 1: Make probability of membership for each cluter >= 0.1
    # ================================================================
    pi_min_potential = pm.Potential(
        'pi_min_potential', T.switch(T.min(pi) < .1, -np.inf, 0))
    # ================================================================

    # The multinomial (and by extension, the Categorical), is a symmetric
    # distribution. Using this as a prior for the indicator variables Z
    # makes the likelihood invariant under the many possible permutations of
    # the indices. This invariance is inherited in posterior inference.
    # This invariance model implies unidentifiability and induces label
    # switching during inference.

    # Resolve by ordering the components to have increasing weights.
    # This does not deal with the parameter identifiability issue.
    order_pi_potential = pm.Potential(
        'order_pi_potential',
        T.sum([T.switch(pi[k] - pi[k-1] < 0, -np.inf, 0)
               for k in range(1, K)]))

    # Indicators, specifying which cluster each primary entity belongs to.
    # These are draws from Multinomial with 1 trial.
    init_pi = stats.dirichlet.rvs(alpha.eval())[0]
    test_Z = np.random.multinomial(n=1, pvals=init_pi, size=n_pe)
    as_cat = np.nonzero(test_Z)[1]
    Z = pm.Categorical(
        'Z', p=pi, shape=n_pe, testval=as_cat)

    # ATTEMPT 2: Give infinite negative likelihood to the case
    # where any of the clusters have no users assigned.
    # ================================================================
    # sizes = [T.eq(Z, k).nonzero()[0].shape[0] for k in range(K)]
    # nonempty_potential = pm.Potential(
    #     'comp_nonempty_potential',
    #     np.sum([T.switch(sizes[k] < 1, -np.inf, 0) for k in range(K)]))
    # ================================================================

    # ATTEMPT 3: Add same sample to each cluster, each has at least 1.
    # ================================================================
    # shared_X = X.mean(0)[None, :]
    # shared_y = y.mean().reshape(1)
    # X = T.concatenate((shared_X.repeat(K).reshape(K, F), X))
    # y = T.concatenate((shared_y.repeat(K), y))

    # Add range(K) on to the beginning to include shared instance.
    # Z_expanded = Z[pids]
    # Z_with_shared = T.concatenate((range(K), Z_expanded))
    # pid_idx = pm.Deterministic('pid_idx', Z_with_shared)
    # ================================================================

    # Expand user cluster indicators to each observation for each user.
    pid_idx = pm.Deterministic('pid_idx', Z[pids])

    # Construct masks for each component.
    masks = [T.eq(pid_idx, k).nonzero() for k in range(K)]
    comp_sizes = [masks[k][0].shape[0] for k in range(K)]

    # Component regression precision parameters.
    beta = pm.Gamma(
        'beta', alpha=a0, beta=b0, shape=(K,),
        testval=np.random.gamma(a0, b0, size=K))
    # Regression coefficient matrix, with coeffs for each component.
    W = pm.MvNormal(
        'W', mu=mu0, tau=T.diag(coeff_precisions), shape=(K, F),
        testval=np.random.randn(K, F) * std)

    # The mean of the observations is the result of a regression, with
    # coefficients determined by the cluster the sample belongs to.

    # Now we have K different multivariate normal distributions.
    X = T.cast(X, 'float64')
    y = T.cast(y, 'float64')
    comps = []
    for k in range(K):
        mask_k = masks[k]

        X_k = X[mask_k]
        y_k = y[mask_k]

        n_k = comp_sizes[k]
        precision_matrix = beta[k] * T.eye(n_k)

        comp_k = pm.MvNormal(
            'comp_%d' % k,
            mu=T.dot(X_k, W[k]), tau=precision_matrix,
            observed=y_k)
        comps.append(comp_k)
```

The first two approaches fail to ensure non-empty clusters; attempting to sample results in a `LinAlgError`:

```
with gmreg:
step1 = pm.Metropolis(vars=[pi, beta, W])
step2 = pm.ElemwiseCategoricalStep(vars=[Z], values=np.arange(K))
tr = pm.sample(100, step=[step1, step2])
...:     

Failed to compute determinant []
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-c7df53f4c6a5> in <module>()
      2     step1 = pm.Metropolis(vars=[pi, beta, W])
      3     step2 = pm.ElemwiseCategoricalStep(vars=[Z], values=np.arange(K))
----> 4     tr = pm.sample(100, step=[step1, step2])
      5 

/home/mack/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc3/sampling.pyc in sample(draws, step, start, trace, chain, njobs, tune, progressbar, model, random_seed)
    155         sample_args = [draws, step, start, trace, chain,
    156                        tune, progressbar, model, random_seed]
--> 157     return sample_func(*sample_args)
    158 
    159 

/home/mack/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc3/sampling.pyc in _sample(draws, step, start, trace, chain, tune, progressbar, model, random_seed)
    164     progress = progress_bar(draws)
    165     try:
--> 166         for i, strace in enumerate(sampling):
    167             if progressbar:
    168                 progress.update(i)

/home/mack/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc3/sampling.pyc in _iter_sample(draws, step, start, trace, chain, tune, model, random_seed)
    246         if i == tune:
    247             step = stop_tuning(step)
--> 248         point = step.step(point)
    249         strace.record(point)
    250         yield strace

/home/mack/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc3/step_methods/compound.pyc in step(self, point)
     12     def step(self, point):
     13         for method in self.methods:
---> 14             point = method.step(point)
     15         return point

/home/mack/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc3/step_methods/arraystep.pyc in step(self, point)
     87             inputs += [point]
     88 
---> 89         apoint = self.astep(bij.map(point), *inputs)
     90         return bij.rmap(apoint)
     91 

/home/mack/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc3/step_methods/gibbs.pyc in astep(self, q, logp)
     38 
     39     def astep(self, q, logp):
---> 40         p = array([logp(v * self.sh) for v in self.values])
     41         return categorical(p, self.var.dshape)
     42 

/home/mack/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc3/blocking.pyc in __call__(self, x)
    117 
    118     def __call__(self, x):
--> 119         return self.fa(self.fb(x))

/home/mack/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc3/model.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    423     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    424         point = Point(model=self.model, *args, **kwargs)
--> 425         return self.f(**point)
    426 
    427 compilef = fastfn

/home/mack/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    604                         self.fn.nodes[self.fn.position_of_error],
    605                         self.fn.thunks[self.fn.position_of_error],
--> 606                         storage_map=self.fn.storage_map)
    607                 else:
    608                     # For the c linker We don't have access from

/home/mack/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    593         t0_fn = time.time()
    594         try:
--> 595             outputs = self.fn()
    596         except Exception:
    597             if hasattr(self.fn, 'position_of_error'):

/home/mack/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/op.pyc in rval(p, i, o, n)
    766             # default arguments are stored in the closure of `rval`
    767             def rval(p=p, i=node_input_storage, o=node_output_storage, n=node):
--> 768                 r = p(n, [x[0] for x in i], o)
    769                 for o in node.outputs:
    770                     compute_map[o][0] = True

/home/mack/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/nlinalg.pyc in perform(self, node, (x,), (z,))
    267     def perform(self, node, (x,), (z, )):
    268         try:
--> 269             z[0] = numpy.asarray(numpy.linalg.det(x), dtype=x.dtype)
    270         except Exception:
    271             print 'Failed to compute determinant', x

/home/mack/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.pyc in det(a)
   1769     """
   1770     a = asarray(a)
-> 1771     _assertNoEmpty2d(a)
   1772     _assertRankAtLeast2(a)
   1773     _assertNdSquareness(a)

/home/mack/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.pyc in _assertNoEmpty2d(*arrays)
    220     for a in arrays:
    221         if a.size == 0 and product(a.shape[-2:]) == 0:
--> 222             raise LinAlgError("Arrays cannot be empty")
    223 
    224 

LinAlgError: Arrays cannot be empty
Apply node that caused the error: Det(Elemwise{Mul}[(0, 1)].0)
Inputs types: [TensorType(float64, matrix)]
Inputs shapes: [(0, 0)]
Inputs strides: [(8, 8)]
Inputs values: [array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=float64)]

Backtrace when the node is created:
  File "/home/mack/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc3/distributions/multivariate.py", line 66, in logp
    result = k * T.log(2 * np.pi) + T.log(1./det(tau))

HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.
```

...which indicates the component is empty, since the precision matrix has shape `(0, 0)`.

The third method actually resolves the empty component issue but gives very strange inference behavior. I selected a burn-in based on traceplots and thinned to every 10th sample. The samples are still highly autocorrelated but much better than without thinning. At this point, I summed the Z values across the samples, and this is what I get:

```
In [3]: with gmreg:
    step1 = pm.Metropolis(vars=[pi, beta, W])
    step2 = pm.ElemwiseCategoricalStep(vars=[Z], values=np.arange(K))
    tr = pm.sample(1000, step=[step1, step2])
   ...:     
 [-----------------100%-----------------] 1000 of 1000 complete in 258.8 sec

...

In [24]: zvals = tr[300::10]['Z']

In [25]: np.array([np.bincount(zvals[:, n]) for n in range(nusers)])
Out[25]: 
array([[ 0,  0, 70],
       [ 0,  0, 70],
       [ 0,  0, 70],
       [ 0,  0, 70],
       [ 0,  0, 70],
       [ 0,  0, 70],
       [ 0,  0, 70],
       [ 0,  0, 70],
       [ 0,  0, 70],
       [ 0,  0, 70],
       [ 0,  0, 70],
       [ 0,  0, 70],
       [ 0,  0, 70],
       [ 0,  0, 70],
       [ 0,  0, 70],
       [ 0,  0, 70],
       [ 0,  0, 70],
       [ 0,  0, 70],
       [ 0,  0, 70],
       [ 0,  0, 70]])
```

So for some reason, all of the users are being assigned to the last cluster for every sample.

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm just trying to figure out how to use infinite clusters ...

Comment: Besides numerical imprecision, shouldn't all of the entries in `pm.Dirichlet('pi', a=alpha, shape=K)` be non-zero?  The support for the Dirichlet is 0 < x_i < 1 for all i entries.

Comment: Also, in my experience instead of shape `K` in `pm.Dirichlet('pi', a=alpha, shape=K)`, I think you want `pm.Dirichlet('pi', a=alpha, shape=(len(alpha), K))`.   ... Or maybe it's `pm.Dirichlet('pi', a=alpha, shape=(K, len(alpha)))`; I forget.

Answer (score 2):

I have run into a similar problem. Something like this worked for a mixture of multivariate gaussians model. As for whether it's the *best*, it's certainly the best solution I've found.

```
pm.Potential('pi_min_potential', T.switch(
                                           T.all(
                                                [pi[i, 0] < 0.1 for i in range(K)]), -np.inf, 0))
```

The key here is that you need to account for *each* potential that is below your cutoff. Further, you should adjust the `shape` of your `pi` distribution, as mentioned in the comments. This will affect your indexing in the `T.switch` call (on the `pi[i,0]`).